# All 2 element combinations of arrays that follow a rule

Tags: algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I have been studying algorithms and optimization and I got stuck on the following challenge and I'm seeking some guidance on how to solve this.

Given 2 desc ordered distinct arrays of `N` and `M` sizes `(N>M)`, write a function that returns an array with all possible 2 element (x, y) combinations of both array that follow the rule: if `x1 > x2` then `y1 > y2`

Example:

```
Input:

A = [4,3,2,1]
B = [20,10]


Output:
[
  [(4,20), (3,10)],
  [(4,20), (2,10)],
  [(4,20), (1,10)],
  [(3,20), (2,10)],
  [(3,20), (1,10)],
  [(2,20), (1,10)]
]
```

I'm doing this function in Java but I'd appreciate answers in any programming languages.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Since the arrays are in descending order, is it not all the pairs?

Comment: I either don't understand the rule, or I don't understand the example. The example you have shown follows the rule `x1 > x2 and y1 > y2`. For the if-then rule you have given the example output would be a lot bigger (for instance, it should contain `[[(3, 20), (4, 10)], [(3, 10), (4, 20)]]`, and the same for all other pairs with `x1 < x2`).

Answer (score 0):

Since both arrays are ordered descending, all you need to do is pick the other element *to the right* of the first, and you've guaranteed the ordering of the pair.

And apparently you want to do this for both arguments, and make pairs from them.

In partly un-idiomatic Haskell (using indices so it is closer to an imperative pseudocode); with list comprehensions:

```hs
foo xs ys  =  [                               -- list of 
                 [                            --  lists of
                   [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ]       --   pairs of pairs, where
                     | (j,y1) <- jys,         --    for each elt y1 in ys, pick each
                          y2  <- drop j ys    --    y2 to the right of it in ys
                   ]
                 |                            --  where
                 (i,x1) <- ixs,               --   for each x1 in xs,
                    x2  <- drop i xs ]        --   pick each x2 to the right of it in xs
    where
    ixs = zip [1..] xs     -- make indexed pairs
    jys = zip [1..] ys
```

Running it:

```
> foo [4,3,2,1] [30,20,10]
[ [[(4,30),(3,20)],[(4,30),(3,10)],[(4,20),(3,10)]] ,
  [[(4,30),(2,20)],[(4,30),(2,10)],[(4,20),(2,10)]] ,
  [[(4,30),(1,20)],[(4,30),(1,10)],[(4,20),(1,10)]] ,
  [[(3,30),(2,20)],[(3,30),(2,10)],[(3,20),(2,10)]] ,
  [[(3,30),(1,20)],[(3,30),(1,10)],[(3,20),(1,10)]] ,
  [[(2,30),(1,20)],[(2,30),(1,10)],[(2,20),(1,10)]] ]
```

List comprehensions are just loops.

To follow your example this needs to be flattened one level down. This can be achieved by post-processing with a specialized flattening function (in Haskell that's `concat`), but can also be achieved just by re-arranging the loops:

```hs
bar xs ys  =  [  [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ]
                 |                       --
                 (i,x1) <- ixs,          -- for each x1 in xs,
                    x2  <- drop i xs,    -- pick each x2 to the right of x1 in xs
                 (j,y1) <- jys,          -- and for each y1 in ys,
                    y2  <- drop j ys ]   -- pick each y2 to the right of y1 in ys
    where
    ixs = zip [1..] xs     -- make indexed pairs
    jys = zip [1..] ys
----
----
> bar [4,3,2,1] [30,20,10]
[ [(4,30),(3,20)],[(4,30),(3,10)],[(4,20),(3,10)],
  [(4,30),(2,20)],[(4,30),(2,10)],[(4,20),(2,10)],
  [(4,30),(1,20)],[(4,30),(1,10)],[(4,20),(1,10)],
  [(3,30),(2,20)],[(3,30),(2,10)],[(3,20),(2,10)],
  [(3,30),(1,20)],[(3,30),(1,10)],[(3,20),(1,10)],
  [(2,30),(1,20)],[(2,30),(1,10)],[(2,20),(1,10)] ]
```

which is what you wanted.